# How to simplify to use ISNULL with LEFT OUTER JOIN to merge tables

Tags: sql, null, left-join, multiple-columns

I need to merge below Table 1 & Table 2 as indicated in "Merge".

[image]

The query I wrote below works; but it is TOO SLOW! Is there any simpler way which returns it faster?

```
SELECT T1.Loc, T2.SO, T2.PO, T1.Item
FROM Table1 T1

LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 T2
ON ISNULL(T1.[SO2],T1.[SO1]) = T2.[SO]
```

Answer (score 0):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  Always use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
     Table2 T2
     ON COALESCE(T1.[SO2], T1.[SO1]) = T2.[SO];
```

There is no need to join to `Table2` twice (much less getting a Cartesian product).  I prefer `COALESCE()` to `ISNULL()` simply because the former is the ANSI standard function for replacing `NULL` values.

I should add that for performance, two joins might be preferable:

```
SELECT T1.Loc, COALESCE(T2_2.SO, T2_1.SO) as SO,
       COALESCE(T2_2.PO, T2_1.PO) as PO, T1.Item
FROM Table1 T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
     Table2 T2_2
     ON T1.[SO2] = T2_2.[SO] LEFT OUTER JOIN
     Table2 T2_1
     ON T1.[SO1] = T2_1.[SO] AND T1.[SO2] IS NULL;
```

It is easier for the SQL engine to optimize joins that use only equality and `AND` conditions, on the clean column references (that is, the columns are not the arguments to any function calls).

Answer (score 0):

Hope this SQL full fill your requirement.

```
Select T2.Loc, T2.SO, T2.PO, T1.item from table 2 T2 join table1 T1
on T1.SO1 = T2.SO;
```